# Haskell Undefined type constructor "Fractional"

Tags: haskell, types, constructor

Why am I getting this error? This is my code, simple one also! Just trying to calculate 1st and 2nd degree equations.  What am I doing wrong here?

I am new to this and I really need to make this work.

```
solveEcGrad1 :: Fractional -> Fractional-> Fractional
solveEcGrad1 a b = - b / a


solveEcGrad2 :: Floating a => a -> a -> a -> (a, a)
solveEcGrad2 a b c     = let delta = sqrt  (b ^ 2 - 4 * a * c)
                in
                    ((-b + delta) / 2 * a, (-b - delta) / 2 *     a)


main::IO()

main = do 
      putStrLn("1.Ecuatie de grad unu:");
      putStrLn("2.Ecuatie de grad doi:");


   opt<-getLine;

    if opt=="1" then do

        putStr("a, din ax+b=0 este:");
        f<-getLine;
        nr<-return(read f:: Fractional );
        putStr("b, din ax+b=0 este:");
        f1<-getLine;
        nr1<-return(read f1:: Fractional );
        p<-return( solveEcGrad1 nr nr1);
        putStr("rezultatul ecuatiei de grad 1 este:");
        putStrLn (show p);
        main;

    else if opt=="2" then do


        putStr("a, din ax^2+bx+c=0 este:");
        e<-getLine;
        n<-return(read e:: Floating);
        putStr("b, din ax^2+bx+c=0 este:");
        e1<-getLine;
        n1<-return(read e1:: Floating);
        putStr("c, din ax^2+bx+c=0 este:");
        e2<-getLine;
        n2<-return(read e2:: Floating);
        p1<-return( solveEcGrad2 n n1 n2);
        putStr("rezultatul ecuatiei de grad 2 este:");
        putStrLn (show p1);
        main;           

    else

        putStrLn("Terminare program.");
```

Comment: Those semicolons in your `do` block are unnecessary and considered bad style, as are the parentheses around the arguments to `putStr` and `putStrLn`.

Answer (score 4):

`Fractional` is not the name of a type; it is instead a *typeclass* like `Floating`.  The signature of `solveEcGrad1` thus needs to be changed to:

```
solveEcGrad1 :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a
```

Similarly, the `read f :: Fractional` and `read e1 :: Floating` expressions need to be changed to use an actual type name instead of `Fractional` and `Floating`; the simplest option is to just replace both typeclass names with `Double`.

Comment: I tried that, it still gets me that error , it was my first thought but it didn't work..

Comment: @user3412387: Could you copy all of the errors you're getting into your question?

Comment: what do you mean by type name ? I tried to replace all Fractional, Floatings with Double, still there was an error..

Comment: @user3412387: By "type name" I mean the name of a type (`Int`, `Double`, `String`, `IO ()`) rather than the name of a typeclass (`Integral`, `Fractional`, `Monad`).  Again, post all of your errors in your question so I can see exactly what's going wrong.

Comment: I'll also note that when I applied all of my changes to your code, it compiled without any errors (There was a warning about defaulting a type constraint, but that doesn't really matter).

Comment: So now I replaced all there is Fractional/Floating with Double and I get this: "Undefined class "Double" "

Comment: @user3412387: Don't replace the `Floating` in the signature of `solveEcGrad2`.  That one stays.

Comment: I am sorry but I did this also and I get this : ERROR file:.\pb2.txt:1 - Undefined class "Double"

Comment: @user3412387: If you changed the type signature of `solveEcGrad1` as I suggested above, you shouldn't change the `Fractional` there either.  You seriously need to go back to studying Haskell before you write anymore of it.

Comment: well I didn't really study this, but I need to make this work, and I don't get why you say stuff like that, I would be more than thankful to see the code as you applied the changes and it worked. I am here to be helped to learn, not to be criticized, thank you !

Comment: I got it in the meantime, sorry for using your time, I am a little embarassed, thanks though !